# Can anyone please tell me why my code is not working properly

Tags: c++, linked-list, palindrome

I have written a piece of code to determine whether a linked list is a palindrome, but it's not working properly. Can you please explain what's wrong with my code?

```cpp
Node* reverse(Node* head) {
    if (head == NULL || head->next == NULL) {
        return head;
    }
    Node* curr = head;
    Node* prev = NULL;
    Node* nx;
    while (curr != NULL) {
        nx = curr->next;
        curr->next = prev;
        prev = curr;
        curr = nx;
    }
    return prev;
}

bool isPalindrome(Node* head) {
    Node* rev = reverse(head);
    while (rev && head) {
        if (rev->data != head->data) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            rev = rev->next;
            head = head->next;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You do know that your `reverse` function modifies the linked list in place, right? So the check afterwards compares the list to itself, not a reversed copy

Comment: What is the goal of your program, finding a palindrome.  Or writing a doubly linked list?
but I think `rev = rev->next;` should be `rev = rev->prev`... oh reverse reverses the list... but then what does `head = head->next ;` do?. So instead of making a reverse function why not start your rev variable at the end of the list (no need to reverse the whole list).

Comment: With proper `const`, you might spot one issue.

Comment: Your code mixes up two different approaches, either could work on their own, but the way you have combined them does not work. Approach 1 is to reverse one list, so you end up with two lists, one is the reverse of the other. Then you scan forward in the two lists checking if they are the same, if they are then the original list was a palindrome. Approach 2 is to simultaneously scan forwards and backwards in the same list, again checking that the scans are the same, if they are then the list is a palindrome. Note this approach does not require creating a reversed list.

Answer (score 1):

You are modifying the list in your reverse function.
Just traverse the list simultaneously from the tail and head and compare. If you already have the tail, then great, just use the second function with a specific tail.
Anyhow, don't modify the list just traverse in a reverse order like this:

```
Node* getTail(Node* head) {
    if (!head)
        return head;
    Node* curr = head;
    while (curr->next) {
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    return curr;
}

bool isPalindrome(Node* head) {
    Node* tail = getTail(head);
    while (head && tail) {
        if (head->data != tail->data) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            head = head->next;
            tail = tail->prev;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```